# Apache Camel Aggregation - out of memory issue

Tags: apache-camel, eai

I have to create a large XML using Camel. Basically, I use smaller messages and finally aggregate all to create the final XML using Camel aggregator.

My issue is that it throws out of memory error when I create large XML file. For smaller XML files, it creates without any issues.

I checked the persistent XML repository such as LevelDB, but that helps in managing persistence during a crash to recover the aggregated message; not exactly deals with memory issues - we tried LevelDb repository along with aggregator as well, but did not help in resolving the memory issue.

I cannot do simple appending as the output is an XML file. If it had been a CSV, I can just append it to an existing file.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use streaming. Set streaming to true on the routes.

Comment: Streaming is used for input file. For me, I meed to create output file. Will that help? Thanks